# How to connect Raspberry Pi to Google Docs

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Is there a way to send data (RFID Scanner's Data) to Google Docs from Raspberry Pi?

I want to send the data that's coming in from RFID tag to Google Docs, so that I can retrieve the users' information from the doc and display it back to him.

Comment: So what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We won't write your code for you. I suggest using python to read the data over RFID with a script and posting it via Google doc's API.

Google documentation:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib

Gist of RaspPi and RFID code
https://gist.github.com/mattgorecki/6085344